# Legend get reverse in arabic jpgraph

Tags: pdf, arabic, jpgraph, ar-php

I am creting a pie chart for web and pdf view in my application ( it is a multilingual site (english + arabic)).
for web version I am using JQplot js plugin for creating pie charts which is working fine for both english and arabic views for pdf I am using Jpgraph php library .
for pdf version in arabic view the issue is legends are coming in reversed order.

[web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVQov.png)

[pdf view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVth7.png)

here is the code I am using for generating pie chart for pdf .

```
function create_graph($chart_array, $plan_id,$lang,$site_lang){

require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/application/third_party/jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php';   
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/application/third_party/jpgraph/src/jpgraph_pie.php';  

if(!empty($chart_array)){
    foreach($chart_array as $chart){
        if ($site_lang=='ar') {
            $leg[] =  $this->utf8_strrev($chart['0']); // to fix the reverse order issue originally it was only ($leg[] =  $chart['0'] - no condition)
        }else{
            $leg[] =  $chart['0'];
        }

        $data[] = $chart['1'];
    }  

    $flag = true;
    foreach($data as $_data){
        if($_data != 0)
            $flag = false;
    }
    if(!$flag){
    // Create the Pie Graph. 
          $graph = new PieGraph(1000,950,"auto"); 
          $graph->SetShadow(); 
          $graph ->legend->Pos( 0.25,0.8,"right" ,"right"); 
          //$graph->legend->SetFont(FF_VERDANA,FS_BOLD,12); 
          $graph->title->SetMargin (20);  

          // Create plots 
          $size=0.25; 
          $p1 = new PiePlot($data); 
          $p1->SetLegends($leg);
          $p1->SetSize($size); 
          $p1->SetGuideLines(true,false); 
          $p1->SetGuideLinesAdjust(1.8,3); 
          $p1->SetCenter(0.25,0.32); 
          //$p1->value->SetFont(FF_VERDANA); 
          $p1->title->Set($lang->line('initial_investment_data')); 

          $p1->title->SetMargin(45); 
          $p1->SetSliceColors(array('red','orange','yellow','green','purple','blue','brown','black'));  
          $graph->Add($p1); 
          $graph->Stroke('assets/graph/initial_investment_'.$plan_id.'.png');
    }
}
}
```

to fix the reverse order issue I have used the following

```
function utf8_strrev($str){
    preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
    return join('', array_reverse($ar[0]));
}
```

In this all I am getting is reversed string with spaces ( ex: bug changes into g u b ) , So the word looses it meaning .

I cannot find why jpgraph is reversing the legends , and how to fix this reverse issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved , A colleague helped me with this .

This is a issue not with Jpgraph but with php gd library , When creating graph image php Gd library reverting the legend text due to font.
To solve this we have used an extension ar-php

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ar-php/

```
You need to do the following:

1) download library and put that in your project 
2) Include the library file 
3) Create a object of the class 
4) user the object to convert the legend in Arabic with correct font .
```

code below:

```
require_once '/application/third_party/ar-php/I18N/Arabic.php';

$Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Glyphs');

$this->Arabic->utf8Glyphs( $legend_name );
```

This will work fine.